# How can I get the values of selected 'Option' , to "A" and "B"?

Tags: jquery, json, select

```
<select id="A" multiple='multiple'>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
</select>
<select id="B" multiple='multiple'>
    <option value="4"></option>
    <option value="5"></option>
    <option value="6"></option>
</select>
```

the options are dynamic,so i can't set ids for them.
after that,how can I do to get a JSON object like:

```
{ A: [value:1,value:3] , B : [value:4] }?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`$.fn.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns an array if there are multiple options:

> In the case of `<select multiple="multiple">` elements, the .val() method returns an array containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns null.

So, it's basically this:

```
var data = {
    A: $('#A').val() || [],
    B: $('#B').val() || []
}
```

Because of the possible `null` return value, I've added the `|| []` cast to turn the result in an empty array instead.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
$('#A').val(); and $('#B').val();
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v22vh/)**